# Python xarray/pandas evaluating a function at multiple grid points

Tags: python, pandas, grid, python-xarray

I am trying to evaluate a function at all grid points of a 240x262 grid, but this requires some optimalization. I am new to Python; usually I would just use a for loop looping over all grid points, and evaluating the function at every point one by one. But surely, a better way could be thought of using python and I have tried many things but have not succeeded :-( I hope somebody can help me or move me on the right track.

Below is an example of the code I would have used, but the function is too complex to do this in a reasonable amount of time. So I have two questions:

1. Is there a better way than using a for loop in evaluating this array?
2. I do not need to evaluate the function at *all* grid points. Can I mask it easily using NaNs? Such that the function only gets used on non-NaN grid points, without actually going into this grid point (i.e. with a for loop).
   X and Y are just 1D (time-axis) arrays, nothing fancy, coming from a dt x nlat x mlon 3D array. Maybe you can also generate a function inserting the 3D field directly....

```
nlat = 240
mlon = 262
A = np.zeros([nlat,mlon])

for i in np.arange(0,nlat-1):
    for j in np.arange(0,mlon-1):
        A[i,j] = function(x,y)
        
            
df = xr.DataArray(A)
df.to_netcdf('A.nc')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should start from the basics by learning numpy before going to xarray.

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

def function(x, y):
    return x - y

x = np.random.rand(240, 1)
y = np.random.rand(262)

df = xr.DataArray(np.vectorize(function)(x, y))
```

There may be other more efficient ways, but you can vectorize the function in numpy and then just feed the arrays to it. Since you want them to become 2D, you need to make one a vertical column (you can use np.reshape if you can't create it that way).

You'll get a numpy array as the result and can use that to create an xr DataArray.